# django: more complicated filter

Tags: django, filter

I have these models:

class A(Model): 
   pass

class B(Model): 
   a = ForeignKey(A)

class C(Model): 
   b = ForeignKey(B)

I have an instance of A called mya.

I want to find all B's for my A, for which there is at least one C.  I can do this in one line:

bsiwant = [c.b for c in C.objects.filter(b__a==mya)] (and uniquify it somehow)

...but presumably that would cause many queries.  Is there a way to do it with the filter such that a single query would be performed?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this should do it:

```
B.objects.filter(a=mya, c__b__isnull=False)
```

or

```
B.objects.filter(a=mya, c__b=F('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vals = C.objects.filter(b__a=mya).select_related("b").distinct()
bsiwant = [c.b for c in vals]
```

Should do it in a single query.